# Aligning objects with GridBagLayout

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to create a calculator that computes the area and circumference/perimeters of triangles, circles, and rectangles.  I have almost everything done but can't for the life of me figure out how to get the GridBagLayout to work.  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gvxo.jpg) is an album of what I currently have and what I want it to look like. I've pasted my GridBagLayout for just my triangle calculations since that is giving me the most difficult time.

```
final JPanel triPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());    
final GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 0, 0);

    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    triPanel.add(heightInt); //height instructions
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    triPanel.add(triHeight); //height textfield
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    triPanel.add(baseInt); //base instructions
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    triPanel.add(triBase); //base textfield
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    triPanel.add(side2Int); //side2 instructions
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    triPanel.add(triSide2); //side2 textfield
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    triPanel.add(side3Int); //side3 instructions
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    triPanel.add(triSide3); //side3 textfield
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    triPanel.add(rectCalc); //calculate button
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    triPanel.add(Triangle); //image
```

In between here I have an ActionListener set up for the "Calculate" button.  In the ActionListener I have another panel that shows up after the calculate button is pressed. Then finally I add the panel to the frame and set the frame as visible.

```
triJFRame.add(triPanel);
triJFRame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: I think you will find it easier to do nested panels with simpler layouts.

Comment: Yeah, nested panels or GridLayout, not GridBagLayout.  GridBagLayout is for automated GUI layout tools.  It's something only a computer could love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the instance of the `GridBagConstrains` to the `add()` method.

Also note that it is not necessary to write "Enter height:" (it is probably
even against the design guidelines), instead we write "Height:".

**GridBagLayout example**:

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GridBagLayoutTriangle extends JFrame {

    public GridBagLayoutTriangle() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("Triangle");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel imgPanel = new JPanel();
        imgPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        imgPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());

        final JPanel triPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        triPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 0, 5, 5));
        final GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.insets.left = 5;
        gbc.insets.top = 5;

        triPanel.add(new JLabel("Height:"), gbc); 

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        triPanel.add(new JTextField(10), gbc); 

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        triPanel.add(new JLabel("Base:"), gbc); 

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        triPanel.add(new JTextField(10), gbc); 

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        triPanel.add(new JLabel("Side 2:"), gbc); 

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        triPanel.add(new JTextField(10), gbc); 

        gbc.gridx = 2;
        triPanel.add(new JLabel("Side 3:"), gbc); 

        gbc.gridx = 3;
        triPanel.add(new JTextField(10), gbc); 

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 2;
        gbc.gridwidth = 4;
        gbc.insets.top = 10;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        triPanel.add(new JButton("Calculate"), gbc); 

        gbc.gridy = 3;
        gbc.insets.bottom = 10;
        triPanel.add(imgPanel, gbc); 

        add(triPanel);

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GridBagLayoutTriangle ex = new GridBagLayoutTriangle();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Instead of the image, I have used a panel with an etched border.

[image: GridBaglayout triangle]

Your layout is a very simple one and you are having difficult time for a reason.
While `GridBagLayout` is a flexible layout manager, it is a complicated one.
This stems from the fact that we need to define each cell individually.

I have also created two examples with `MigLayout` manager and `GroupLayout` manager.
They are easier to use and more portable. (One of the big drawbacks of the `GridBagLayout`
manager is that it is not resolution independent.)

**MigLayout solution**

`MigLayout` is a very flexible third-party layout manager. I find it always the easiest
to create a layout with this manager. The manager is resolution independent.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;


public class MigLayoutTriangle extends JFrame {

    public MigLayoutTriangle() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("MigLayout triangle");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JPanel imgPanel = new JPanel();
        imgPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        imgPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());        

        JPanel pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout("wrap 5", "[right][][right]"));

        pnl.add(new JLabel("Height:"));
        pnl.add(new JTextField(10));
        pnl.add(new JLabel("Base:"));
        pnl.add(new JTextField(10), "wrap");

        pnl.add(new JLabel("Side 2:"));
        pnl.add(new JTextField(10));
        pnl.add(new JLabel("Side 3:"));
        pnl.add(new JTextField(10), "wrap");      

        pnl.add(new JButton("Calculate"), "spanx, center");
        pnl.add(imgPanel, "spanx, center");

        add(pnl);

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MigLayoutTriangle ex = new MigLayoutTriangle();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image: MigLayout triangle]

**GroupLayout solution**

`GroupLayout` is IMO the most powerful built-in manager. The interesting thing about
this manager is that is has only a few options to set but it is very capable. The manager
is also resolution independent. `GroupLayout` is also the default manager used by
NetBeans GUI builder.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.CENTER;
import static javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle;


public class GroupLayoutTriangle extends JFrame {

    public GroupLayoutTriangle() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("GroupLayout triangle");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        Container pane = getContentPane();
        GroupLayout gl = new GroupLayout(pane);
        pane.setLayout(gl);

        JLabel heightLbl = new JLabel("Height:");
        JLabel baseLbl = new JLabel("Base:");
        JLabel side2Lbl = new JLabel("Side 2:");
        JLabel side3Lbl = new JLabel("Side 3:");

        JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field3 = new JTextField(10);
        JTextField field4 = new JTextField(10);

        JButton calcBtn = new JButton("Calculate");

        JPanel imgPanel = new JPanel();
        imgPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        imgPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        imgPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());          

        gl.setAutoCreateGaps(true);
        gl.setAutoCreateContainerGaps(true);   

        gl.setHorizontalGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(CENTER)
                .addGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(heightLbl)
                                .addComponent(side2Lbl))
                        .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                                .addComponent(field1)
                                .addComponent(field3))
                        .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(baseLbl)
                                .addComponent(side3Lbl))
                        .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup()
                                .addComponent(field2)
                                .addComponent(field4)))
                .addComponent(calcBtn)
                .addComponent(imgPanel)
        );

        gl.setVerticalGroup(gl.createSequentialGroup()
                 .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(heightLbl)
                        .addComponent(field1)
                        .addComponent(baseLbl)
                        .addComponent(field2))
                .addGroup(gl.createParallelGroup(BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(side2Lbl)
                        .addComponent(field3)
                        .addComponent(side3Lbl)
                        .addComponent(field4))
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(calcBtn)
                .addPreferredGap(LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(imgPanel)
        );

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GroupLayoutTriangle ex = new GroupLayoutTriangle();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The groups were judiciously chosen in order to have the labels right-aligned.

[image: GroupLayout triangle]

Comment: Wow thank you for the thorough explanation of alternatives to GridBagLayout!  Yeah it was very ambitious of me to move from FlowLayout to GridBagLayout.  I guess I should have so more experience with Java GUIs.  What you wrote is exactly what I wanted to do.  Thanks again!